# How to increment a list with a variabe who change his value on each reboot in a loop in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I have a problem.
I want to make a shopping list who asking to the user what item does it want and how many.
The list will evolve on each time the loop "reboot" by adding the name of the item (a string) and the number it is associated with (an integer).
The only problem is that when the loop "reboot", the contents of the list is reset.

Here is the code:

```
def shopping(n):
  x=0
  while x<n:
    item={}
    nb={}
    shopping_cart={}
    item[x]=str(input("item?")) #We asking the user the name of the item he wants.
    nb[x]=int(input("nb?")) #We asking the user the number he wants.
    shopping_cart[x] = item[x],nb[x]
    shopping_cart+=shopping_cart[x] #We try to add what the user has entered to a dictionary to not reset what he has entered before.
    x+=1
  print(shopping_cart)
shopping(2) #To simplify, in this exemple, we imagine that the customer want to buy two differents items.
```

But, on the console I have this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'tuple'
```

I don't find a way to not reset what the customer said before...

Ps: Sorry for my English, I'm French... :)

Comment: The first thing you do in your loop is create new dictionaries, getting rid of the existing values.  Move the dictionary creation outside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for this note! But I tried this and the original problem is not resolved.

Comment: Specifically your issue is the way you're trying to add to the `shopping_cart` dict, but that in turn is caused by your use of a not meaningful key (your loop counter). In general, `dict['key_with_some_meaning'] = 'value_for_that_key'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below function will return a dictionary of the items the user wants to purchase to the number of each item they want.

```
def shopping(n):
    cart = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        item = input("What would you like to buy?")
        amount = int(input("How many would you like?"))
        cart[item] = cart.get(item, 0) + amount
    return cart
```

Comment: I like this approach better. I think this answer would be better if it also explained why this is using data structures like `dict` better than the OP. You also dropped an `input` on the 2nd line of the loop body.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't think about cart.get ! I modified a little bit the code and I don't have any error and everything works!